# Most secure way to hash passwords

Tags: security, hash

I have that methods (pseudocode):

```
string predefinedsalt = "03jf0j02j302jf0j3f08h3298fbckm91jr192jr091j2-r01"

string dynsalt(user)
{
    return md5(user.id)
}
```

And to hash password I want to use one of these ways:

1. `md5(user.password)`
2. `md5(user.password + predefinedsalt)`
3. `md5(user.password + dynsalt(user))`
4. `md5(md5(user.password) + dynsalt(user))`

Which of these ways is more secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your suggestions is save for hashing passwords. Use a slow hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt and let the function generate a salt from the random source of the OS.

Password cracker tools already implement such combinations with MD5 out of the box, and MD5 is ways too fast. One can calculate about [100 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) with common hardware.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think that computer with 8 x NVidia Titan X's is _common hardware_. Also, you might want to include [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) to the list.

Comment: @1615903 - You are right, what I meant is, that every determined attacker can order such off-the-shelf hardware for a reasonable price, there is no special knowledge involved for building such hardware (as would be the case for government agencies).